# PHP array_diff returns all results

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I am reading a text file and putting the contents which are file id's into an array.

I then have a new array with the same id's but one extra.

My aim is to compare these two arrays and print out the new file id or file id's

The problem I have is that When I use the function `array_diff`, it prints everything and not the actual difference between the two arrays.

```
$results = array_diff($pNewList, $pSavedList);
        $resultsCount = count($results);
        for($x = 0; $x < $resultsCount; $x++){
            echo $results[$x].'<br/>';
        }
```

my output is printing every line even though the contents are the same in both arrays

Comment: what is the value in your arrays `$pNewList` and `$pSavedList`

Comment: I'll bet anything one of the arrays has newlines in the values, the other doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar or may be space at the end or beginning of the array values

Comment: in my file, each file id is printed on a new line,

Comment: @joe show your array values here bro

Comment: first array - Array ( [0] => 1PuRg-sYXdvTCdgLSaRmiZoreB5kHckqctqkgnNHJp7o [1] => 1l9F22N-dj4OI1gZo7tZ2LhdZPV-wYCDe2CLsVPLMjZ4 [2] => 1jEylMiRK7yFRsvjOeHKoQw5xSFqmz2jkmBNezlLlI98 [3] => 0B_5k2xcMXwlmNU04Qm01TG9wWUk )

Comment: second - Array ( [0] => 1PuRg-sYXdvTCdgLSaRmiZoreB5kHckqctqkgnNHJp7o [1] => 1l9F22N-dj4OI1gZo7tZ2LhdZPV-wYCDe2CLsVPLMjZ4 [2] => 1jEylMiRK7yFRsvjOeHKoQw5xSFqmz2jkmBNezlLlI98 [3] => 0B_5k2xcMXwlmNU04Qm01TG9wWUk [4] => 1QjJpJkdRGa_EnbBVdU2yhcHF8pa5FwEboBmjNTfvCOY )

Comment: my results array is the same as my second array

Comment: @SatishSharma I have just tested this by hardcoding 2 arrays and it works, why won't it work with my two arrays? also, my first array = $fileList = json_decode($_POST['arrayInput']);, as I am getting the array from javascript

Comment: @SatishSharma I have found the problem  ! . the length of each element is 2 bigger in my second array than the first array, this is why. I think its a problem when I am reading my file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$results = array_diff($pNewList, $pSavedList, TRUE);
$resultsCount = count($results);
for($x = 0; $x < $resultsCount; $x++){
    echo $results[$x].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Warning: array_diff(): Argument #3 is not an array